# oracle apex Error handling function not working properly

Tags: oracle, error-handling, oracle-apex

I am trying to use the oracle's apex_error package to implement error handling in my app.

1. test app: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145329:2:11482099171656::NO:::
2. table created: constraint_lookup
3. function provided by oracle "apex_error_handling_example". https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/Example-of-an-Error-Handling-Function.htm#AEAPI2216
4. The solution works fine except when you click on the error it gives error in console instead of taking you to the tab of the IR report.
   [image: when you try to add duplicate DeptID it gives error from constraint_lookup table as expected]
5. Now click on the message so it should take you to the duplicate DeptID, but it just gives you error in the console.
   [image: error in console]
6. I have tried to handle this at page level, application level also I tried to set the column_alias manually so I don't have to use the APEX_ERROR.AUTO_SET_ASSOCIATED_ITEM but all in vain.

Any help and your time will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is something I tried to do as well. At the moment I don't think it's possible to correctly link into an interactive grid from the error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeffrey for taking out time and reply. Even if it does not work the errors in the console are getting on my nerves :)